# Export project from Unity to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, unity-game-engine

Can I export a project done in Unity to Microsoft Visual Studio?

I tried selecting my project from menu *Preferences->External Script Editor->Microsoft Visual Studio*, but when I run the application, I get this error:

```
A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly
```

Have I done something wrong? If so, what?

Comment: That's because you can't run a class library, there's no executable for it. You don't directly run DLL's.

Comment: And I can use classes and my code in a WPF project?

Comment: I can't answer that, as I'm unfamiliar with Unity development in VS. However, C# is C#. Even if your Unity Class Library isn't portable, you should be able to reuse code through linking project files. You may want to add a tag to your question so that people familiar with Unity are more likely to see it.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft have now acquired UnityVS company SyntaxTree, and are offering the UnityVS plugin for free for Visual Studio 2010-2013 Professional or higher. This should allow you to run Unity projects from within Visual Studio.

You can [download it here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/07/29/visual-studio-tools-for-unity-1-9.aspx), or get it from the Visual Studio Extensions Gallery.